finding the finite series $f[n]$ given its length and its DFT
suppose the number $N$ is even and $f[n]$ is a series with length $N$ and a DFT $F[k]=(-1)^k$ how can I find the series $f[n]$.
so far I've tried this: since $N$ is even and $F[k]$ is even and real we can say that $f[n]$ is even and real.
$$f[n]=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{(-1)^k}e^{j2 \pi \frac{nk}{N}}=...=\frac{1}{N}(1-e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}n})\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}e^{j\frac{2 \pi}{N}n(2k) }$$
but I don't really see how i can continue from here. also I was thinking maybe using the DTFT but still didn't really saw how to begin.

Do you know what the DFT of $-1, 1, -1, 1, \dots$ is? Can you use that along with some properties of the DFT to derive what the IDFT of that sequence is?

Notice that $F[k] = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{N} \frac{N}{2}k} G[k]$, where $G[k]$ is the "all-ones" sequence. Now, if you know the IDFT of $G[k]$ and use the properties of the DFT you will get your answer
